# How do i get GRUB to display environment variables in label components?

Tags: grub2, time, date

So, I've been trying without much success to get the current date + time to display on the boot menu.

I read [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84140/how-to-set-a-variable-equal-to-the-output-from-a-command-in-grub2) that loading the `datehook` module would help, as it added several new variables for weekday, month, year, etc.

Here's what I've tried:

```
+ label {
    id = "time"
    text = "$hour : $minute : $second"
    color = #ffffff
}
```

The problem here is, the quotes make it so that it doesn't treat the `$` as an operator. But at the same time, if I don't wrap that in quotes, it throws an error!

```
+ label {
    id = "time"
    text = "@HOUR@ : @MINUTE@ : @SECOND@"
    color = #ffffff
    }
```

I tried this because I figured that since other there GRUB variables with this syntax that print their values seemingly without a hitch (e.g., `@KEYMAP_SHORT@`), it would work the same.